# Dropwizard, testing a fat jar

Tags: maven, unit-testing, dropwizard, maven-shade-plugin, fatjar

Hey I am really desperate. I want to build a fat jar with Dropwizard (and Maven) but I realize the shade plugin won't include test classes so no tests are running.
Is there an easy way to run those tests with a "clean install" goal. I can't believe dropwizard 's getting started page tells you to use this shade plugin if it has tests problems.
Please help me!!

Comment: Hmm, you should refresh your knowledge about the Maven's build phases. Here is a sample output of my toy project with Dropwizard: https://gitlab.com/zloster/dropwizard-static/-/jobs/205091850 Before the "shading" step (`52618 [INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:3.2.1:shade (default) @ dropwizard-static ---`) you will see the unit tests and integration tests execution results.

Comment: I am really sorry, I panic big time and the bug was because of another thing. Surefire plugin has a bug in a particular version and when i runned it in a docker container the tests weren't recognized. SORRY

Answer (score 0):

I am really sorry, I panic big time and the bug was because of another thing. The Surefire plugin has a bug in a particular version and when I ran it in a docker container the tests weren't recognized. SORRY